# Is $f'(I)$ a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

If $f:I \to R$ $f$ is differentiable and where $I$ is an open interval in $R$, then is $f'(I)$ a closed set? I'm trying to show that $R \backslash f'(I)$ is open by saying that if a point is not the value of the derivative I can find some open interval around it that is also not the value of the derivative? I'm not sure if this is the right approach and am struggling to make progress!

Thanks

Comment: It is always an interval,sometimes trivial. (Darboux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily open, nor closed. Consider $f(x)=x^3$ with $I=(-1,1).$

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x) = {1 \over 2} x^2$, then $f'(U) = U$ for any set $U$, open or not.